# INDEX Creation Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, indexing, database-performance

I have a table with 30M rows and one of the columns I need to create an INDEX on. What would be the fastest way to do this? Two options I have considered is truncating the table, adding the index, and then re-importing the SQL as a csv file. The other would be the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

What should I do for the fastest performance?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use ALTER TABLE. If you truncate, alter and re-import then you will have to wait while the truncate runs, then while the re-import runs which will be added to by building the new index. With just the ALTER the only time will be building the new index, so it skips the truncate and import time.

However, with 30M rows, building the index could take some time and may timeout. If this happens you will need to increase the timeouts somehow (I don't use MySQL so I can't tell you how). If this doesn't work, you may have no choice but to do the truncate and re-import route, hopefully using some sort of Bulk upload.